# Google font rendering is pixelated

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, font-awesome

Can anyone tell me why the Lato Google font looks pixelated here http://zenandinno.com/test/ but not here http://www.savantgenius.com/brilliance/? I've been trying to figure it out for a few days now, I would really appreciate any help you may have. Warmest regards.

Comment: Which specific regions of text are you comparing from each page?